# Throw HttpResponseException in Breezejs enabled webapi controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

I'm using BreezeJs on both server and client side. I have the following controller action. I wish to get an 404 http code when a product code is not found.

```
public Product GetProduct(string code)
    {
        var p = _contextProvider.Context.Products.Where(p => p.Code == code).FirstOrDefault();
        if (p == null)
        {
            //does not work because because breeze swallows the exception
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return p;    
    }
```

Below is the response. The HttpResponseException is swallowed by the BreezeApi. Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

```
{

    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference",
    "ExceptionType": "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException",
    "StackTrace": " at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )\r\n at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute1[T0,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0)\r\n at Breeze.WebApi.ODataActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync>b__0(HttpResponseMessage response)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40(Task`1 t)\r\n at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)"

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [action filter Breeze is using](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.WebApi/ODataActionFilter.cs) is not designed to handle `NULL` Content values.

You can work around it if you generate the not found response this way, Note there is some content in this Not Found repsonse i.e. the string message.

```
public HttpResponseMessage  GetProduct(string code)
{
    var p = _contextProvider.Context.Products.Where(p => p.Code == code).FirstOrDefault();
    if (p == null)
    {
       Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Couldn't find the resource");
    }
    Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, p);
}
```

I think this is a bug in Breeze.

The code for Breeze should probably be altered to not attempt to parse faulted responses (`!actionExecutedContext.Response.IsSuccessStatusCode`) or make proper use of its `TryGetContentValue` and escape the method if it fails to retrieve the content (as it stands it ignores the false returned if it fails to retrieve the content).

```
public class ODataActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the action is executed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionExecutedContext">The action executed context.</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(!actionExecutedContext.Response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return;
        }
```

And/Or at least a simple Null reference check here:

```
public class ODataActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the action is executed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actionExecutedContext">The action executed context.</param>
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        object responseObject;
        if(!actionExecutedContext.Response.TryGetContentValue(out responseObject))
        {
            return;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed now in breeze 0.73.1.  i.e. throwing a HttpResponseException will now return that exception to the client.

Comment: @ChauHoMan - Should be fixed now. If Jay's answer (and fix) satisfied you, please click the tick mark under the up/down to indicate that you accept it. If not, let us know and we'll keep digging. Thx

Comment: @Ward the fix checked in was an exact duplicate of my recommended solution and diagnosis - with no attribution or reference back to this question.

Comment: Sorry, Mark!  Just scrambling to catch up with all of the requests. Your diagnosis and solution were right on. We appreciate it!

Comment: @JayTraband no worries, well done on turning the fix around so quickly.